# JavaScript string array custom sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ecmascript-6, comparator

Hi there I am trying to implement a custom string comparator function in JavaScript. There are some special values that I want them to be always before other, with the rest just being alphabetically sorted.
For example, if I have an array ("very important" "important", "Less important") are three special values(should have order as above)

```
    ["e","c","Less Important","d","Very Important","a",null,"Important","b","Very Important"].
```

After sorting , the array should be( if there's a null or undefined value, need to place in the last)

```
    ["Very Important", "Very Important", "Important", "Less Important" "a","b","c","d","e",null]
```

how can I write a comparator function for the requirement above? 
(im using a comparator api of a library, so i cannot sort the array but need to implement the logic with a comparator( like compareTo in java which returns 0,1,-1)

thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

- move `null` values to bottom,
- move `'Very Important'` strings to top,
- move `Important'` strings to top and
- sort the rest ascending.

```js
var array = ["Important", "e", "c", "d", "Very Important", "a", null, "b", "Very Important"];

array.sort((a, b) =>
    (a === null) - (b === null) ||
    (b === 'Very Important') - (a === 'Very Important') ||
    (b === 'Important') - (a === 'Important') ||
    a > b || -(a < b)
);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you! How does the function take care of the second special value "Important"? also how can i make your logic into a comparator function that returns -1,0,1?

Comment: the deltas returns a numerical value.